# Linear span of polynomials of degree at most 8

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}_8[t]$ the set of all polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $8$. Consider the set of the following polynomials $$\mathcal{F}=\{(t-1)^3t^k\}_{k=0}^{5}\cup \{(t+1)^3t^k\}_{k=3}^{5}$$

How to show that polynomials $(t+1)^3, (t+1)^3t, (t+1)^3t^2$ lies in the linear span of $\mathcal{F}$?

I was trying to show that $(t+1)^3$ is linear combination but failed.

I guess that this is not a difficult question. Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Can you use the Wronskian?

Comment: @gt6989b, nope!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. Your vector space $\mathcal{P}_8$ maps to $\mathbb{R}^9$ by mapping the polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + \ldots a_8x^8 \mapsto (a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_8)^T$, and then you need to map the basis $\mathcal{F}$ and needed vectors, and do the usual linear algebra approach to this problem.

Exactly the same constants on the linear combination should produce same results in both $\mathcal{P}_8$ and $\mathbb{R}^9$.